# how to fix php-mode indenting when using closures

Tags: php, emacs, indentation, php-mode

I use php-mode in Emacs, it work fine execept when I use closures as argument like this:

```php
$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
        echo "foo";
    });
```

It seams that when function is inside function invocation the indentation is doubled. How to fix this?

**EDIT**

How to make it look like this (the same as javascript-mode handle anonymous functions).

```php
$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    echo "foo";
});
```

Comment: Doesn't that make sense? It seems to indent 4 spaces for every open parenthesis, be it a round one or a curly one.

Comment: It simply should be a way to add somekind of hook that will add 0 indentet to function if it's inside argument and 4 when outside

Comment: Could you please edit the question to show what you would like the indentation to be?

Comment: Thanks for the EDIT! One more question though, if you don't mind: how should the whole block be indented if you hit ENTER after `'/'`? Or after `function()`?

Comment: @Thomas with new line after '/' is fine the same as for javascript mode aligned to '/' (in the same column).

Comment: @jcubic what is the version number of `php-mode` you use?

Comment: @slitvinov I try 1.5.0 and 1.6.5 from github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help from [@amalloy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625403/amalloy) I manage to create this fix that solve the problem:

```lisp
(defun unident-closure ()
  (let ((syntax (mapcar 'car c-syntactic-context)))
    (if (and (member 'arglist-cont-nonempty syntax)
             (or
              (member 'statement-block-intro syntax)
              (member 'block-close syntax)))
        (save-excursion
          (beginning-of-line)
          (delete-char c-basic-offset)))))

(add-hook 'php-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (add-hook 'c-special-indent-hook 'unident-closure))
```

not sure If it need to be in php-mode-hook or not

Great help was `C-c C-s` that show what will be in `c-syntactic-context` variable when `c-special-indent-hook` is fired (and it's after indent was done).

[CC-Mode Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html) also help

**UPDATE**

I found this code that is invalid

```
array('tags' => array_map($rows,function($row) {
....    return array(
....        'name' => $row['name'],
....        'size' => $normalize($row['tag_count']);
....    );
....});
```

(dots are the spaces that need to be removed)

and another one

```
return array('tags' =>
             array_map($rows, function($row) use ($normalize) {
             ....    return array(
             ....        'name' => $row['name'],
             ....        'size' => $normalize($row['tag_count']);
             ....    );
             ....});
```

so I need to modify the function, `C-c C-s` shows that `arglist-cont-nonempty` appear twice (each additional `arglist-cont-nonempty` add more indent that need to be removed)

```lisp
(defun unident-closure ()
  (let ((syntax (mapcar 'car c-syntactic-context)))
    (if (and (member 'arglist-cont-nonempty syntax)
             (or
              (member 'statement-block-intro syntax)
              (member 'brace-list-intro syntax)
              (member 'brace-list-close syntax)
              (member 'block-close syntax)))
        (save-excursion
          (beginning-of-line)
          (delete-char (* (count 'arglist-cont-nonempty syntax)
                          c-basic-offset))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you put point at the end of the first line and press C-c C-o, you can see what syntactic construct cc-mode thinks you're in the middle of, and customize how it indents that construct. I don't have php-mode on my current computer, but I think setting this to zero worked reasonably well back when I was doing PHP.

Comment: It's `topmost-intro` and it's already set to 0, but next line is `statement-block-intro` and it's set to `+` can it be 0 if inside `topmost-intro` was before?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code in jcubic's answer and it no longer workers. Based on amalloy's helpful answer, I've modified jcubic's workaround to the following, which works.

```lisp
(defun unident-closure ()
  (let ((syntax (mapcar 'car c-syntactic-context)))
    (if (and (member 'arglist-cont-nonempty syntax)
             (or
              (member 'statement-block-intro syntax)
              (member 'brace-list-intro syntax)
              (member 'brace-list-close syntax)
              (member 'block-close syntax)
              (member 'defun-block-intro syntax)
              (member 'defun-close syntax)))
        (save-excursion
          (beginning-of-line)
          (delete-char (* (count 'arglist-cont-nonempty syntax)
                          c-basic-offset))))))
```

Comment: Did you donwload latest version of php-mode, I beleive they fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes - still faced the issue. Issue is still open on Github too. I've provided the amended work around (they referenced your answer), hopefully a fix in the mode will be released soon.