# How to display all syntactic symbols from php mode in Emacs?

Tags: php, emacs, syntax

How to get a list of all syntactic symbols? like when you type `M-x c-set-offset` you get one of them. I have my old code (from this question [how to fix php-mode indenting when using closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482667/how-to-fix-php-mode-indenting-when-using-closures)), that use `c-syntactic-context` but it seams only work for `c-special-indent-hook` because Emacs say that the variable is void.

I want it for php mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `M-x c-set-offset` and then hit TAB.  The completion buffer will show you all the symbols.